# Display hidden element with the help of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code in a jsfiddle and I want to display one hidden element `<div id="e1"></div>`

I have written code for this in jquery like this:

```
$("#credit4").sortable({    
    receive: function (event, ui) {
        ui.item.remove();
        var s="PLEASE SELECT ANOTHER BLOCK";
        $("#e1").show();
        $("#e1").html(s);
        setTimeout('$("#e1").hide()',1500);
    }
});
```

`credit4` is the id of a draggable element and when the user wants to drag the element then this hidden elemet should be displayed.

You can also check my jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/sanjayrathod7/5cZD5/44/.
Please suggest me where I'm wrong.

Comment: strange, funny thing is he the .hide() works as expected...

Comment: You might remove the irrelevant code from that fiddle. It's massive. Also, consider using HTML classes and each() rather than running the exact same code on multiple IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find out the answer

Try this

```
$( "#credit4" ).draggable({
revert: true,
  start: function( event, ui ) {
        var s="PLEASE SELECT ANOTHER BLOCK";
       $("#e1").show();
      $("#e1").html(s);
        setTimeout('$("#e1").hide()',1500);      
       }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified fiddle with a set of alerts in place indicating which line is hiding #e1. You can see that you're probably hiding it when you didn't intend to (at lines 45 and 171):

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/5cZD5/50

```
$("#credit").sortable({
    receive: function (event, ui) {
        ui.item.remove();
        $("#e1").show();
        $("#e1").html(s);
        setTimeout('$("#e1").hide()', 1500);  alert('hiding 10');
    }
});
```

Comment: I want to display element with the id e1 when user try to drag and drop element - 1)Accumulated depreciation 2)Bank 3)Car